# converting to uppercase in ascx.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, uppercase

I currently have the following code which transforms the first letter of the surname to uppercase;

```
static string UppercaseFirst(string s)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    char[] a = s.ToCharArray();
    a[0] = char.ToUpper(a[0]);
    return new string(a);
}
```

I now want to edit it so it changes all the letters in the surname to uppercase.
Should be a simple one but my ascx.cs knowledge is dire! :)
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`return s.ToUpper();`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ewdd6aed.aspx) or a variant of, [`ToUpperInvariant()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.string.toupperinvariant.aspx), etc.

There are a number of ways to do this to be 'culturally safe', depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
static string UppercaseFirst(string s)
{
    return s.ToUpper();
}
```